# Video files freeze/loop while audio continues to play

Tags: linux-mint, video

When starting the video, monitor flickers on and off 2 times and video freezes or loops on the few first seconds while audio plays as normal, and seek bar moves as it should.
Jumping ahead on the seek bar results in monitor flickering off/on 2 times again and video freezing/looping on the frame jumped to.

Youtube and other online video hostings work fine.
Videos in .3gp|.avi formats worked fine.
mp4client works for mp4 videos that didn't work with other players.
.mkv format has the same problem, but not with all files, 1964 year b&w Addams Family series plays fine for some reason.

Tried Celluloid, VLC, and mpv.
Tried reinstalling mint-meta-codecs and installing ubuntu-restricted-extras instead. No difference.
Video resolution doesn't seems to matter. Checked with a same mp4 video downloaded from youtube from 1080 to 144p.

Freshly installed Linux Mint 21 with MATE GUI.
LiveCD with Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS has the same problem.

Still have Mint 19 with Cinnamon GUI on another partition. No problem there.

If no help with main problem, maybe you can help bypass it?
What is the difference between how mp4client and VLC plays back the video? Are there players with more broad capabilities that work same way as mp4client? Preferably with multiple formats and subtitles support.